# writing to text file in MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, text-files, mpi

I'm trying to write to text file with MPI but the file is not created.
I need only to write at the master (rank = 0), but nothing works.
It only working when I running the program in console (and save corrupt element)  and not in Mpich2 and
I attached the code.
Thanks for helping.

```
  /* -*- Mode: C; c-basic-offset:4 ; -*- */
/*
 *  (C) 2001 by Argonne National Laboratory.
 *      See COPYRIGHT in top-level directory.
 */

/* This is an interactive version of cpi */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int  namelen, numprocs, rank;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);    
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name,&namelen);
    MPI_Status status;
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt","wb+");

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            fprintf(f,"%d \n",i);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If only one process is writing, you don't need that fancy `MPI_File` stuff. Just right the file as you usually do. But as it seems, you let the other processes write too, which contradicts your earlier statement.

Comment: I tried to write the file with Just FILE type but is not working. this is just the example. what I need is to write the file from the master after he will get the results from the slaves.

Comment: This looks like C! Do not add tags for unrelated, different languages.

Comment: sorry ! I'm kind of new here..:)

Comment: *"what I need is to write the file from the master after he will get the results from the slaves"* So? Just collect the results in the Master, then `fprintf` them like you would do in plain standard C.

Comment: I tried it. it's not working.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Right now, you do not even attempt to communicate between the processes. Is that the real issue here, communication between processes via MPI?

Comment: No. this is just the sample code. I need to create text file from the master after I will do some calculations. I tried to do this with Just FILE type in C but the file is not created. so from what I read I thought I need to create and manage file in MPI and this method also not working.

Comment: @OfirN Then please post some sample code that actually reproduces the problem, i.e. a [mcve]. Right now, it is impossible to tell what your problem is in the first place.

Comment: I edited the code to explain my problem.

Comment: Hm, with francis' modification, that code should work fine, but I do not feel like setting up MPI on my Windows PC and try it tbh.

Answer (score 4):

In the sample code you posted, all processes open the file and only process 0 closes it. Could you try the following modification ?

```
if (rank == 0) {
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt","wb+");
    if(f==NULL){printf("failed to open file: permission issue ?\n");exit(1);}
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
        fprintf(f,"%d \n",i);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Since your code seems to come from the Argonne National Laboratory, I suppose that it is ran on a cluster using a particular file system. 
The following code is based on yours. It makes use of `MPI_File_open()` and `MPI_File_write()` on a single process, using `MPI_COMM_SELF`.

```
/* This is an interactive version of cpi */
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int  namelen, numprocs, rank;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);    
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name,&namelen);
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_File fh;


    if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_SELF, "test.txt",MPI_MODE_CREATE | MPI_MODE_WRONLY,MPI_INFO_NULL,&fh);
        //FILE* f = fopen("test.txt","wb+");
        //if(f==NULL){
        //printf("failed to open file\n");exit(1);
        //}
        for (int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            char buf[42];
            //fprintf(f,"%d \n",i);
            snprintf(buf,42,"%d \n",i);
            MPI_File_write(fh,buf,strlen(buf), MPI_CHAR,&status);
        }
        //        fclose(f);
        MPI_File_close(&fh);
    }
    else {
        // do nothing
    }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Please make sure that you hae the permission to write in the considered folder. Make sure that all nodes can access this folder ! Try some folders like your folder in `/tmp` or `/scratch`... Your cluster may have some sort of documentation somewhere telling you where you can write files !

Comment: It seems to work on my personal computer. Are you working on a cluster featuring a particular file system ? Can you create a file in this folder ?

Comment: I solved the problem. The problem was with the file path. Thank you all for helping !